logic app Unable to extract json from email attachment
So l am trying to extract json file from an email attachment.
I then l try to parse json the file but don't get the content of the json file itself.

What l want to then do is assign the first and last name to a variable and use that later on in the logic app.
I have used a combination of the following for the content in the json control :
base64(triggerBody()?['attachments']?['ContentBytes'])
base64ToString(body('Getattachment')?['attachments']?['ContentBytes'])
but keep the following message :
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'body('GetAttachment')?['Attachments'][0]?['ContentBytes']' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Can you share the content of the GetAttachment body, just before the next action fails? No need to share the real data, only the structure (the schema) is important.

It worked for me using below design:

base64ToString(body('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['contentBytes'])


Input attachment:
{
"firstName":"Rithwik",
"lastName":"Bojja"
}


Output:

